# comparing rows in Sql, without using distinct operator? (distinct operator implementation)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to compare twos rows from a query result, for instance, if 1st row is equal to 2nd Row.

Given a query of the form

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

if the query results 100 rows, then how do we compare each rows for equality. just i am curious about the sql server how it will implement. basically implementation of Distinct operator.  just want to know the how the SQL server will implement in behind the process. as it will help to understand the concept more in clearer way.

Comment: why downvote ??? just asking how the implementaion of compare in Tsql.

Comment: You could create a temporary table and use a cursor to loop through rows only putting in rows that are not already in the temporary table. That would separate duplicates. The question is why would you want to do this?

Comment: i asked because just to know, how it works.

Comment: It is likely that it orders all of its rows by the distinct key. Then will compare each row with the next. It can skip over duplicates until it finds one that is not a duplicate and repeat the process. You can find out what it does by inspecting the excution plan. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu

Comment: +1 Valid and interesting question asked.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? You want to compare rows from a result and do what?

Comment: @xbrady check for updated question. i am just curious how the sql will implement in behind the scenes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way the sql server may use - to compare hashes of whole rows:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(*)
from YourTable
```

or choosen columns

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(col1, col2, col3)
from YourTable
```

and if checksums differ - the rows are differ, but if checksum match - it need to check more carefully over exact values of columns, but it will be more or less easier to filter out the results which checksums is not match.

To check the candidates to duplicates:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM(*)
from YourTable
GROUP BY CHECKSUM(*)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I didn't even know that SQL Server provided a CHECKSUM function. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY col1,col2,... -- all columns to test for equality here
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

In the `GROUP BY` you put the name of every column you want to be equal. If you want entire rows to be equal, put down the name of every column in the table there.

Comment: can u give me how the sql implements in behind scenes. check my edited question.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what, your table "in a relational database" will have a primary key that will be used in other tables.

Because of this, your rows 1-100 will all be unique because of that key.

However, if you are trying to compare specific columns, you will need to build a function similar to this:

```
$temp;
$i=0;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
while($stmt->fetch()){

     if($temp!=$name){
          $temp=$name;
          $saveIDs[$i]=$id;
     }

$i++;
}
```

Comment: -1 **will have a primary key** - not true. **Should** have not equal **will** have. And asked about T-SQL, not other language